Laravel LiveWire Newbie : ' Attempt to read property "id" on string'
Pardon the question, as it may be basic, but I seem not to be able to get my headaround it
I am learning the LiveWire UI library(PHP Laravel), and I am following their documentation as part of the learning process.

I was attempting to generate fake data to see the "foreach" loop in action, so that I could gain a better understanding, but it seems as if I am not doing it right, can someone help me please?
View:
livewire.creat-post.blade.php
<div>

    @php

            $posts =  array(
                "id" => "bar",
                "name" => "foo",
            );

    @endphp

    <h1>Title: "{{$title}}" </h1>

    <div>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div wire:key="{{ $post->id }}"> 
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
    @endforeach
    </div>
</div>

Controller:
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class CreatePost extends Component
{


    // 2024-12-22 14:45
    // as per docs https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/components#setting-properties
    
    public $title = 'Post title... RAD Software Systems' ;

    public function render()
    {
       return view('livewire.create-post');

        // return view('livewire.create-post')->with([
        //     'author' => Auth::user()->name,
        // ]);
    }
}

Rendering to localhost browser - see above image : "Localhost: Error Code after Rendering"
I was expecting the foreach loop to print out the array values

Your array is not multi-dimensional; it's a single dimension; in order to loop through it as you expect, wrap your array in an additional array: array(array("id" => "bar", "name" => "foo")).

Thanks for the input. I tried but that wasn't successful. Can you expand upon how to do that?

Please [edit] your question to include your updated attempt.  However, I assume that since the inner array isn't an object, you should just access it as if it was an array instead: {{$post['id']}}.

Use some nested data casting the inner array to objects: $posts = [(object)['id' => 'bar', 'name' => 'foo',], (object)['id' => 'baz', 'name" => 'qux',]];  In this way you don't need to modify the view
